# Xtra Report Perfomance with Large amout of Data

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, xtrareport

I have XtraReports in Devexpress having 1 lacs of data (1326 Pages).. however it takes lots of time to load data in reportviewer.. also takes same amount of time for each page navigating

What is the solution for decrese the time for loading data into reportViewer.

Thanks...

Comment: You've not provided enough information for anyone to give you an answer. Have you tried profiling the application to see where the bottleneck(s) is/are? Do you have any scripts or calculated fields? How about some code?

Comment: I have reports rendering 3k pages in less than 30 sec. Either your development machine is slow or you have a problem (latency) fetching the data from the DB which is then bound to report.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided enough information so I can't help you with loading data to report viewer.
About page navigation: Report fetches all data during initial rendering of report, when you browse through pages and during export. If you want your report to fetch data only on initial report rendering use [report caching](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/e/E1946.aspx).